# Trouble searching User model using django-ajax-selects

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-ajax-selects

I´m using [django-ajax-selects](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-selects/) in my project, and I can´t make it to work with *django.contrib.auth.models.User*. All I want to do is search the *username* field and I don´t know how to put it in my settings.py. What I have now is:

```
AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS = {
    'to' : dict(model='django.contrib.auth.User', search_field='username'),
}
```

If I search one of my models, like this

```
AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS = {
    'to' : dict(model='books.Book', search_field='title'),
}
```

Everything works fine, so I think I just need to know what to put in the model parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after trying many combinations, mysteriously, this worked:

```
AJAX_LOOKUP_CHANNELS = {
    'to' : dict(model='auth.User', search_field='username'),
}
```